# Check Property Using Predicate in Class

Tags: ios, nspredicate

Hello I want to use predicate in my application.In my application, I have one class(named JigsawView) which contains one BOOL property (named isSelected).Now i have one array which contains instances of JigsawView.I want to find that instances whose isSelected property is set to YES using predicate.Please help me.Thanking you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSArray* resultArray = [yourArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isSelected = YES"]]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isSelected == YES"]; 
NSArray *filteredArray = [yourArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```